# localtunnel and CORS not working properly

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cors, localtunnel

I am using localtunnel to expose my backend and frontend. Right now, I have a very simple setup like this one:

```
const httpServer = require('http').createServer();
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const io = socketIO(httpServer, { cors: { origin: '*' } });

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  ...
});

httpServer.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on the port 5000`);
});
```

I then expose this backend with localtunnel with `lt --port 5000`. I then get the URL, set it up in my React frontend, start the frontend app running on port 3000 and then `lt --port 3000`. Then, when I try to connect to the backend, I keep getting this error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://tame-mayfly-63.loca.lt/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NbU6WbU' from origin 'https://spotty-robin-42.loca.lt' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

First I thought this was some error with localtunnel, but then tried with `ngrok` and the error is the same. I am enabling all origins from CORS, so I don't know what might be happening.

Doing `curl "https://tame-mayfly-63.loca.lt/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"` works, but I guess that's because CORS is ignored when making the request with cURL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. Looks like you first need to access to the dynamic url serving your backend and click on "Continue". After doing that, CORS won't be a problem anymore.

Comment: As the page also says, if there are browser specific headers present, it would keep on blocking those untill you specify headers to allow the requests.
The page here means: The hosted page from localtunnel for the url that they have generated.